# Capturing Choice set values from the adaptive card

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, adaptive-cards, mule4

I was wondering how can I capture the selected choice sets values in the adaptive card. Is there a way to capture the response after hitting the Action.submit button?
Below you can see, the selection is an array that shows the titles based on the initial logic and creates a Choices array

```
"body": [{
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "text": "select the recordings you want to delete"
 },
 {
    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
    "isMultiSelect": true,
    "id": "myColor",
    "style": "compact",
    "value": "1",
    "choices": vars.selection
 }
]
```

Comment: Is this a question about Mule 4 or Adaptive Cards? There is not enough context to understand the quest?ion.

Comment: both, am rendering the adaptive card from the http request connector body field

Comment: Mule doesn't render. It is just making an HTTP request to whatever Adaptive Card API is. Try putting the she's in terms of both Mule and cards. Try describing the HTTP request  and response with details.

Comment: I do not have problem with rendering the card, my question is about extracting the choice set values

Comment: Most people familiar with Mule probably don't know about the cards API and values. If you want to extract them inside a Mule application I recommend to specify the problem as how to extract values from a JSON document and provide examples of the values to extract and the expected results